# Logz.io .Net service

Tags: c#, .net-core, logz.io

I want to use Logz.io in `.Net` as a singleton service. The current documentation is not covering this for now. 
This is some code I made until now while trying to understand how can I achive my goal... 
I added `ILogzioService` as a dependency to one of my REST API endpoints and tried to push some data, but I can't see any log in Kibana and I don't get any error neither...

```
    public class LogzioService : ILogzioService
    {
        private readonly string APPNAME = "MyApp0";

        public ILogger logger;
        private ILoggerRepository loggerRepository;
        private Hierarchy hierarchy;
        //private LogzioAppender logzioAppender;

        public LogzioService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

            LogzioAppender logzioAppender = new LogzioAppender();
            logzioAppender.AddToken(config["logzio_key"]);
            logzioAppender.AddType("log4net");
            logzioAppender.AddListenerUrl("listener-nl.logz.io:8071"); // Azure - West Europe
            logzioAppender.AddBufferSize(100);
            logzioAppender.AddBufferTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            logzioAppender.AddRetriesMaxAttempts(3);
            logzioAppender.AddRetriesInterval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            logzioAppender.AddDebug(false);
            logzioAppender.AddGzip(true);
            logzioAppender.JsonKeysCamelCase(false);
            // <-- Uncomment and edit this line to enable proxy routing: --> 
            // logzioAppender.AddProxyAddress("http://your.proxy.com:port");
            // <-- Uncomment this to prase messages as Json -->  
            logzioAppender.ParseJsonMessage(true);
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(logzioAppender);
            hierarchy.Configured = true;

            LogzioAppenderCustomField sourceField = new LogzioAppenderCustomField();
            sourceField.Key = "source";
            sourceField.Value = APPNAME;

            logzioAppender.AddCustomField(sourceField);

            logger = hierarchy.GetLogger(APPNAME);
        }

        public void LogCritical(string message, Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingEventData loggingEventData = new LoggingEventData();
            loggingEventData.Message = message;
            loggingEventData.Level = Level.Critical;
            loggingEventData.Domain = "Domain";
            loggingEventData.ThreadName = "ThreadName";
            loggingEventData.ExceptionString = ex.ToString() + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace;
            loggingEventData.Identity = "Identity";
            loggingEventData.TimeStampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            loggingEventData.LoggerName = "LoggerName";
            loggingEventData.UserName = "UserName";
            loggingEventData.LocationInfo = new LocationInfo(GetType()); // not sure how to use this
            //loggingEventData.Properties = new log4net.Util.PropertiesDictionary(); // not sure how to use this

            // method 1
            LoggingEvent loggingEvent = new LoggingEvent(GetType(), loggerRepository, loggingEventData);
            // method 2
            //LoggingEvent loggingEvent = new LoggingEvent(GetType(), loggerRepository, loggingEventData.LoggerName, loggingEventData.Level, loggingEventData.Message, ex);

            hierarchy.Log(loggingEvent); // not working
            logger.Log(loggingEvent); // not working
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into your code and managed to make it work.
Basically I added `logzioAppender.ActiveOptions();` and added `https://` to the `logzioAppender.AddListenerUrl`.
I highly suggest that you set `logzioAppender.AddDebug(true)` it will show you all the debug logs of the Logz.io appender. Also it takes couple of seconds for the logs to be shipped to Logz.io.
Hope it will work for you :)

```
    public class LogzioService : ILogzioService
    {
        private readonly string APPNAME = "MyApp0";

        public ILogger logger;
        private ILoggerRepository loggerRepository;
        private Hierarchy hierarchy;

        public LogzioService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

            LogzioAppender logzioAppender = new LogzioAppender();
            logzioAppender.AddToken(config["logzio_key"]);
            logzioAppender.AddType("log4net");
            logzioAppender.AddListenerUrl("https://listener-nl.logz.io:8071"); // Azure - West Europe
            logzioAppender.AddBufferSize(100);
            logzioAppender.AddBufferTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            logzioAppender.AddRetriesMaxAttempts(3);
            logzioAppender.AddRetriesInterval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            logzioAppender.AddDebug(false);
            logzioAppender.AddGzip(true);
            logzioAppender.JsonKeysCamelCase(false);
            // <-- Uncomment and edit this line to enable proxy routing: --> 
            // logzioAppender.AddProxyAddress("http://your.proxy.com:port");
            // <-- Uncomment this to prase messages as Json -->  
            logzioAppender.ParseJsonMessage(true);

            LogzioAppenderCustomField sourceField = new LogzioAppenderCustomField();
            sourceField.Key = "source";
            sourceField.Value = APPNAME;
            logzioAppender.AddCustomField(sourceField);
            
            logzioAppender.ActiveOptions();

            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(logzioAppender);
            hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
            hierarchy.Configured = true;
            logger = hierarchy.GetLogger(APPNAME);
        }

        public void LogCritical(string message, Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingEventData loggingEventData = new LoggingEventData();
            loggingEventData.Message = message;
            loggingEventData.Level = Level.Critical;
            loggingEventData.Domain = "Domain";
            loggingEventData.ThreadName = "ThreadName";
            loggingEventData.ExceptionString = ex.ToString() + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace;
            loggingEventData.Identity = "Identity";
            loggingEventData.TimeStampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            loggingEventData.LoggerName = "LoggerName";
            loggingEventData.UserName = "UserName";
            loggingEventData.LocationInfo = new LocationInfo(GetType());


            LoggingEvent loggingEvent = new LoggingEvent(GetType(), loggerRepository, loggingEventData);

            hierarchy.Log(loggingEvent);
            logger.Log(loggingEvent);
        }
    }
```